# OpenCV 3 C++ : library not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to setup OpenCV 3 in Eclipse (Windows) using Cygwin C++ compiler.

**Cygwin Path** : "C:\cygwin64" (already included in System Path)

**OpenCV Include Path** : "E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\install\include"

**OpenCV Library Path** : "E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib" (has all libraries eg.libopencv_highgui310)

When I am trying to build a face detection c++ code

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

Error output,

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib/libopencv_highgui310.dll.a when searching for -llibopencv_highgui310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib/libopencv_highgui310.dll.a when searching for -llibopencv_highgui310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_highgui310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib/libopencv_objdetect310.dll.a when searching for -llibopencv_objdetect310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib/libopencv_objdetect310.dll.a when searching for -llibopencv_objdetect310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_objdetect310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib/libopencv_imgproc310.dll.a when searching for -llibopencv_imgproc310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible E:\cv\opencv\eclipse\lib/libopencv_imgproc310.dll.a when searching for -llibopencv_imgproc310
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_imgproc310
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:45: recipe for target 'opencv_cpp_v2.exe' failed
```

Can someone help with ths error ?

Comment: Double check to make sure you are consistently using OpenCV 2 or 3, but not both.  Your question asks about 3, but your sample code has 2.

Comment: @MatthewPope The OP's sample is correct; OpenCV 3.* doesn't have a "opencv3"-include directory.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to link a wrong build of OpenCV, e.g. the build for Visual Studio which is ABI-imcompatible with Cygwin/GCC. Build OpenCV yourself with Cygwin and the error should go away.

Comment: @Sai did you build opencv yourself?

Comment: @GPPK Yes, I have built using cmake

Comment: Alright, and how exactly did you configure the build with CMake? Are you sure OpenCV wasn't built with Visual Studio? You could check out this [guide](http://hvrl.ics.keio.ac.jp/kimura/opencv/opencv-3.1.0.html) or [google for others](http://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+cygwin).